# Is my SparkConf correct for a 2vCPU and 8 GB mem?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following Config set for my spark cluster. Do you think its right for 2 cores and 8 gb ? P.S. I am running it on my local machine so assume just one node.

```
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAppName("Welcome Back Pratik").setMaster('local')\
              .set('spark.submit.deployMode', 'cluster')\
              .set('spark.executor.memory','2g')\
              .set('spark.driver.memory','1g')\
              .set('spark.executor.cores',1)\
              .set("spark.executor.instances", 2)\
              .set('spark.memory.offHeap.enabled',"True")\
              .set('spark.memory.offHeap.size','380m')
```

Comment: rather than having two executors (JVMs) each of 1 core, it would very likely be better to have a single executor with 2 cores allowed on it. Generally, we'd have 5 cores per executor

Comment: i would go with a single executor with 2 cores and allocate 7gbs the executor,